# why is the src img is not working i am 100% sure that the src is the same?

Tags: html, css, image

idk why this is happeing it is working in other html files but not in this one
[image]

the image is inside the templates folder and the file i am in is chat.html this is also happeing to me when i try to link to a css file

```
<body>
<div class = "All">
  <div class="AllChats">
    <div class="header">
      <img src="cabin.png" alt="pfp" id="pfp">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Chat">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without seeing your file structure, you may have to do something like this `<img src="templates/cabin.png" alt="pfp" id="pfp">`

Comment: it is still not working

Comment: What does your file structure look like?

Comment: i edited the post with an image of the file structure

Comment: Try `<img src="/cabin.png" alt="pfp" id="pfp">` If that doesn't work, and you should do this anyway, set up a folder called `img` and set your src to `src="img/cabin.png"`. If that doesn't work, try changing the name of your img and use the new name.

Comment: still not working

Comment: Are you developing locally or in production?

Comment: i am developing locally